# load a view from storyboard using custom url scheme while app is running in background

Tags: ios, ios5

I have setup a custom url scheme for my app, this is how it works when app is not running in background:

- custom url link arrives in email, upon clicking brings the login view from storyboard
- Upon clicking the login button will take to the you requested tab in tab controller

So far so good.

Here is the problem I am having:

- If I click on the custom url link again from email When the app has already been loaded once and its running in the background  it does not bring the login view again

My question is what do I need to do load the login view again when I click the custom url link  more than once.

Custom url scheme works perfectly the first time but not when the app has already been running. I tried to debug this ... when I click custom url scheme link "handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url" method is called  in my AppDelegate.m file so what do I need to do to load the login screen again from storyboard and how do I check if the login screen is already loaded in memory ... Login screen is my start view in storyboard, below is how handleOpenUrl function looks like in my app delegate.

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url{
    if(!url){
        return NO;

    }
    // check if email link was clicked
    if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"docova"]) {

        NSString *urlString = [url absoluteString];
        NSLog(@"URL Parameter string: %@", [url query]);
        NSLog(@"incoming url => %@", urlString);
        // NSArray *arrayQStrings=[self getDataOfQueryString:urlString];
        NSDictionary *dict = [self parseQueryString:[url query]];
        NSLog(@"query dict: %@", dict);
        NSLog(@"query dict: %@", [dict valueForKey:@"action"]);
        NSLog(@"query dict: %@", [dict valueForKey:@"docpath"]);

        //[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1]; // tab 3
        //[self.parentViewController.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1]; // tab 3

        /* save user data ***/
        NSUserDefaults *appPrefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [appPrefs setObject:[dict valueForKey:@"action"] forKey:@"action"]; // reset these after using it
        [appPrefs setObject:[dict valueForKey:@"docpath"] forKey:@"docpath"]; // reset these after using it

        // save data to application preference
        [appPrefs synchronize];
         return YES;

    }

    return NO;

}
```

Can someone suggest on how to bring a view from storyboard upfront when the app has already been running. I know there is activity stack in android, is there something like that in ios as well ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using the commnets from mialkan and also have to change the handleOpenUrl method ( this is deprecated) to " application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation", so in my openUrl method, I check for specific action and invoked the view accordingly, see below:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle: nil]; 
loginView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SIDLoginViewController"]; 
self.window.rootViewController = loginView;
```

Thanks mialkan :)

Comment: This helped me with my problem. But I had a NavigationController as the app first responder, and in order to get navigation working in my first view, I had to put an Identifier on the Navigation Controller in the Storyboard and load _it_ up and set it as the rootViewController

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, your interface builder structure like this

Navigation Controller -> Login View Controller -> Tabbar Controller

When your app already run in background, if the user open the app via mail link you want show login view first?

you can use `NSNotificationCenter` to invoke a method to pop to Login view.

Here is a ex. code to register your notification and to call it.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(popToLoginView:) name:@"popToLoginViewNotification" object:nil];
```

To notifiy methods.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"popToLoginViewNotification" object:nil];
```

if you have TabbarController classes put `popToLoginView` method. Or each view controller of tabbar put `popToLoginView` method. in view check if its current view, with this code

```
if (viewController.isViewLoaded && viewController.view.window) {
// viewController is visible
}
```

then pop to login view.

I hope this helps.

Comment: mialkan, thanks for you quick response. But I am not sure if I need to use "NSNotificationCenter" ... all I need to do is be able to bring front the start screen of my storyboard which is the login screen when someone clicks the custom url link. How can I bring the login screen (LoginViewController) to the front from appDelegate when someone clicks on custom url link. Thnx.

Comment: You are welcome. I tested but I dont know project so you can try like this in -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url   UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle: nil];
    loginView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loginView"];
    self.window.rootViewController = loginView;